# PL SQL trigger to insert history record when a column is updated

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers

I would like to insert a row into a history table when **any** column is updated in a table.

I'm just looking to capture the column name, old value and new value.

I'd like this trigger to be as reusable as possible as I'm going to use the same concept on other tables.

I'm familiar with triggers and with how to capture updates on one column.  I'm specifically looking for how to write **one** trigger that inserts a record into a history table for **any** column that gets updated in the history table's corresponding table.

**EDIT 1**
I have stated **NOWHERE** in my post that I'm looking for source code so shame on anyone that downvotes me and thinks that I'm looking for that.  You can check my previous questions/answers to see I'm not one looking for "free source code".

As I stated in my original question, I'm looking for **how** to write this.  I've examined http://plsql-tutorial.com/plsql-triggers.htm and there's a code block which shows how to write a trigger for when ONE column is updated.  I figured that maybe someone would have the know-how to give direction on having a more generic trigger for the scenario I've presented.

Comment: Right. Wanna know how much I charge per hour? SO is not a free coding service. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Adrian - just looking for a little direction here...my question never states I'm looking for anyone to write the code for me...

Comment: Fair enough. The problem is that your question sounds just like a  Spec doc I'm reading at work right now. You have to gives us something.  Have you though of any approach? Have you researched if that's even possible? Have you researched if the RDBMS (oracle) already provides that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=oracle+update+trigger

Comment: @Adrian - I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but I was thinking in PL SQL that there might be a way to loop through the columns in a particular table and retrieve their names to be used with ":old" and ":new" in the trigger.

Comment: @tbone - maybe I'm reading your comment wrong, but the link you pasted is a total slap in my face - it's like you're saying, "Hey stupid, why don't you learn how to search on SO before posting a question?".  I have already searched in the general manner as your comment suggests and I'm looking for a specific answer to a specific problem.

Comment: @ZackMacomber Now you showed you did your homework, which is great. You should have written that in your question. Take a look at Justin Cave's answer below.

Comment: @ZackMacomber sorry Zack, didn't mean it that way, I just saw what looked to be an answer in the 2nd or 3rd listing from that search.  I'll post an answer here if you can't find what you're looking for.  cheers

Comment: @tbone - I'm sorry - I misread your post - you were indeed just trying to give me direction - I should have provided more information up-front as Adrian suggested and then my question wouldn't have looked like a "please write my code for me" sort...thanks for your help

Comment: @ZackMacomber see my answer for a possible option for you

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming a regular table rather than an object table, you don't have a whole lot of options.  Your trigger would have to be something of the form

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  AFTER UPDATE ON table_name
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( UPDATING( 'COLUMN1' ) )
  THEN
    INSERT INTO log_table( column_name, column_value )
      VALUES( 'COLUMN1', :new.column1 );
  END IF;

  IF( UPDATING( 'COLUMN2' ) )
  THEN
    INSERT INTO log_table( column_name, column_value )
      VALUES( 'COLUMN2', :new.column2 );
  END IF;

  <<repeat for all columns>>
END;
```

You could fetch the `COLUMN1`, `COLUMN2`, ... `COLUMN<<n>>` strings from the data dictionary (`USER_TAB_COLS`) rather than hard-coding them but you'd still have to hard-code the references to the columns in the `:new` pseudo-record.

You could potentially write a piece of code that generated the trigger above by querying the data dictionary (`USER_TAB_COLS` or `ALL_TAB_COLS` most likely), building a string with the DDL statement, and then doing an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute the DDL statement.  You'd then have to call this script any time a new column is added to any table to re-create the trigger for that column.  It's tedious but not particularly technically challenging to write and debug this sort of DDL generation code.  But it rarely is worthwhile because someone inevitably adds a new column and forgets to re-run the script or someone needs to modify a trigger to do some additional work and it's easier to just manually update the trigger than to modify and test the script that generates the triggers.

More generally, though, I would question the wisdom of storing data this way.  Storing one row in the history table for every column of every row that is modified makes using the history data very challenging.  If someone wants to know what state a particular row was in at a particular point in time, you would have to join the history table to itself N times where N is the number of columns in the table at that point in time.  That's going to be terribly inefficient which very quickly is going to make people avoid trying to use the history data because they can't do useful stuff with it in a reasonable period of time without tearing their hair out.  It's generally much more effective to have a history table with the same set of columns that the live table has (with a few more added for tracking dates and the like) and to insert one row in the history table each time the row is updated.  That will consume more space but it is generally much easier to use.

And Oracle has a number of ways to audit data changes-- you can `AUDIT` DML, you can use fine-grained auditing (FGA), you can use Workspace Manager, or you can use Oracle Total Recall.  If you are looking for more flexibility than writing your own trigger code, I'd strongly suggest that you investigate these other technologies which are inherently much more automatic rather than trying to develop your own architecture.

Answer (score 4):

You might setup the history table to be the SAME as the main table, + a date and type field.  You only need to capture the old values, as the new values are in the main table.

try this (untested):

```
create or replace trigger "MY_TRIGGER"
before update or delete
on MY_TABLE referencing new as new old as old
for each row
declare
  l_dml_type varchar2(10);
begin
if (updating) then
  l_dml_type := 'UPD';
else
  l_dml_type := 'DEL';
end if;

insert into MY_TABLE_HIST
(
 col1,
 col2,
 col3,
 dml_type,
 dml_date
)
values
(
 :old.col1,
 :old.col2,
 :old.col3,
 l_dml_type,
 sysdate
);
end;
/
```

Comment: +1 - Thanks for this post - I might end up going this direction as it's clean and straightforward

Answer (score 1):

As a note, depending on your design, if space is a limit, you can create a view that would track the changes in the way you were going for, and just show what the record was at the time.

Comment: This seems like a comment and should be posted as such under the question. You need to participate more in the community to gain some reputation before you have commenting privileges. Welcome to SO!